# Is there a better way of writing a function like this

Tags: javascript

The function below takes two arguments and returns an array of objects. Each object should be returned in descending order in reference to the availableBagSizes array.
I gave two examples, I want to know if there is a better solution to achieving the same output and why my solution is bad.

I need help with the third example it's not returning as expected.

```
function getBagCounts(clientOrders, availableBagSizes) {
  // TODO: remove this hard-coded solution for test scenario
  // clientOrders === [9]

  // sorting the availablebag size in descending order
  const newAvailableBag = availableBagSizes.sort((a, b) => b - a);

  const result = [];
  let newRemainder;

  for (let index = 0; index < clientOrders.length; index++) {
    const clientOrder = clientOrders[index];

    // set the newremainder variable to clientOrder for the first loop
    newRemainder = index === 0 ? clientOrder : newRemainder;

    for (let j = 0; j < availableBagSizes.length; j++) {
      const bagSize = newAvailableBag[j];

      const count_result = Math.floor(newRemainder / bagSize);
      newRemainder = newRemainder % bagSize;
      const obj = {};

      if (newRemainder > bagSize) {
        result.push({ size: bagSize, count: 0 });
        continue;
      }

      // checking if it is the last item in the bagSizes
      if (j + 1 === availableBagSizes.length) {
        // setting the newreaminder to the next number of client order
        newRemainder = clientOrders[index + 1];
      }

      result.push({ size: bagSize, count: count_result });
    }
  }
  return result;
}

// first example
const clientOrders = [9];
const availableBagSizes = [1, 2, 4];
const expectedoutput = [
  { size: 4, count: 2 },
  { size: 2, count: 0 },
  { size: 1, count: 1 }
];

// second example
const clientOrders = [5, 12, 12];
const availableBagSizes = [1, 2, 4];
const expectedoutput = [
  { size: 4, count: 1 },
  { size: 2, count: 0 },
  { size: 1, count: 1 },
  { size: 4, count: 3 },
  { size: 2, count: 0 },
  { size: 1, count: 0 },
  { size: 4, count: 2 },
  { size: 2, count: 1 },
  { size: 1, count: 0 }
];

// third example
const clientOrders = [4.5];
const availableBagSizes = [1, 2, 4];
const expectedoutput = [
  { size: 4, count: 1 },
  { size: 2, count: 0 },
  { size: 1, count: 0.5 }
];
```

Comment: If the code is complete and works and you just want improvements, it should be on Code Review. This site is primarily for fixing broken code.

Comment: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: thanks. I will do that

Comment: Why is it bad? Well that is all very subjective but in terms of modern JavaScript conventions we tend to lean towards a more functional style of programming. First absolute no no is that you have mutated an input parameter. Second is for loops are frowned upon these days and we would instead use a reduce function. Doing either of these things in a modern JavaScript tech interview would most likely blow the interview for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [codereview.se]

Answer (score 0):

It looks good to me.

You should think about performance and check of parameters if you want a good code.

```
if (!Array.isArray(clientOrders) || !Array.isArray(availableBagSizes)) {
 return null;
}
```

Also you should try to use [forEarch loop which is faster in performance](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/2090/0/array-loop-vs-foreach-vs-map)

Making a `push` is slow, better make a `.map((element,index)=>{return null})`

It really depends how you manage your data, but I would say first loop is a `forEach`, and second loop you make a `map`. Because whatever the case in your second loop, all the time you make a `push` there would be no `null` or `undefined` return in your mapped array.